# Reportlab: adding image as background

Tags: python, image, reportlab

i'm building an easy pdf document as linked in the following tutorial: [LINK](http://www.tylerlesmann.com/2009/jan/28/writing-pdfs-python-adding-images/), but i have the problem of place a background image into the document, creating something like a watermark.

How i can do this without using Canvas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end, for this complex operations, i've used the Canvas document object, and on that i've placed the background image as "Watermark"